# Why square brackets in the type declaration of an object key?

Tags: typescript

I need this:

```
Impact: = { 0: "Minor", 1: "Major", 2: "Critical" };
```

If I want to annotate the type explicitly, it is:

```
Impact: { [key: number]: string } = { 0: "Minor", 1: "Major", 2: "Critical" };
```

Why not:

```
Impact: { number: string } = { 0: "Minor", 1: "Major", 2: "Critical" };
```

What do the square brackets mean? Is `key` a reserved word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square brackets are mnemonic for the square brackets that you would use to access an element:

```
let Impact: {[key: number]: string} = ...;
console.log(Impact[0]);
```

Compare to a call signature, which can be declared like this:

```
let Impact: {(key: number): string} = ...;
// equivalent shorthand:
// let Impact: (key: number) => string;
console.log(Impact(5));
```

The name `key` is an arbitrary parameter name in both cases.

The `{number: string}` syntax is already used for an object with a single property named `number`.

Comment: Thanks. So the square brackets have nothing to do with arrays?

Comment: I wouldn't say that.  They aren't being used in this case to actually index an array, but they symbolize the square brackets that would be used to index an array; that's why the same symbol was chosen.